# insert equations in lyx

Tags: lyx

I have this problem while inserting a long equation in lyx, it took all the page width and it didn't display all the equation
[image]

Comment: You can use the `multline` environment.

Comment: .. which is available via Insert -> Math -> AMS multline environment. Hit Ctrl + enter to insert a new line.

Comment: Your notation looks a bit odd to me. Don't you need sub and superscripts in more places? Also, you seem to have three different forms of notation for the dinitrogen ion. I suspect it should be N_2^+ though that's code; I don't know how to enter it in LyX.

Comment: thnk you for the answers